# Cannot compile against gobject-2.0

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I am trying to learn the gobject system, so I read some of the documentation on the gnome site and made a simple gobject parented to GObject.  I don't wan't to keep running the `gcc` job every time I want to compile, and I also wanted to learn a build system at the same time.  I tried autotools, which I got working to the point where `pkg-config` searches for gobject-2.0.

To compile my project from the command line, I do:  `gcc *.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-2.0)` (I had to take out the extra ticks for formatting).  Anyway <--- this command works.

However: `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-2.0) *.c`, which SHOULD BE the SAME COMMAND, returns this:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:10:10: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccxO7wkX.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `g_type_init'
main.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `g_type_create_instance'
/tmp/ccPu2beU.o: In function `a_get_type':
myobject.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `g_type_register_static'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Yes, it is the EXACT SAME COMMAND WITH ANOTHER ORDER.  I have no clue what's going wrong.  Here is how autotools/automake does the build:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0    -o GObjectTest main.o myobject.o  
main.o: In function `main':
/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src/main.c:9: undefined reference to `g_type_init'
/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src/main.c:10: undefined reference to `g_type_create_instance'
myobject.o: In function `a_get_type':
/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src/myobject.c:19: undefined reference to `g_type_register_static'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [GObjectTest] Error 1
```

Is this some quirky gcc compile thing?  I tried with clang too no avail, which makes me think that this is a linker problem?  I really have no idea, and was hoping that someone out there will.  This is pretty frustrating.

Here is the "offending code":

```
GType a_get_type (void)
{
  if (type == 0) {
    GTypeInfo info = {
      sizeof(AClass),
      NULL,
      NULL,
      (GClassInitFunc) a_class_init,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      sizeof(A),
      0,
      (GInstanceInitFunc) NULL
    };
    type = g_type_register_static (G_TYPE_OBJECT,
                   "AType",
                   &info, 0);
  }

  return type;
}
```

Edit: Here is the output of my autotools build, the make part anyway:

```
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:10:10: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -MT myobject.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/myobject.Tpo -c -o myobject.o myobject.c
mv -f .deps/myobject.Tpo .deps/myobject.Po
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0    -o GObjectTest main.o myobject.o  
main.o: In function `main':
/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src/main.c:9: undefined reference to `g_type_init'
/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src/main.c:10: undefined reference to `g_type_create_instance'
myobject.o: In function `a_get_type':
/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src/myobject.c:19: undefined reference to `g_type_register_static'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [GObjectTest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aj/Desktop/GObjectTest'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the interesting part: replace `gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0    -o GObjectTest main.o myobject.o` with `gcc -o GObjectTest main.o myobject.o -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0` and it works.

Comment: Not a gcc thing since your gcc line shows that it is not being told where to find the library. There is no -L option and no -l option.

Comment: Could it be that you are using static version of `gobject` library?

Comment: Nope, because the first command I gave works just fine (no -static or -Bdynamic options).  Using `nm` on libgobject-2.0.a actually finds those symbols.  @Scooter: there is, pkg-config finds it and puts it there.

Comment: @Relish Oops, my bad, I forgot to move the scroll bar. What is the output for "how autotools/autobuild does the build" for the one that works?

Comment: Ill edit it in, hang on.... K

Comment: Libraries go at the end of the linker command line. More generally, each library must go after everything that depends on it. This isn't a "quirk", it's just the rule.

Comment: Okay, but autoconf/automake is putting the files at end.  How do I change this?  Also, is that really required?  Of all the software I have compiled I think I've seen a lot of compiling with the object files' names at the end.

Comment: autoconf/automake put the files where you say to put them. The library order is significative (check the `-l` documentation on http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) although in some circumstances - on some GNU/Linux system, for example - it happens to work in mixed order.